# How to improve MYSQL performance on a network

Tags: php, mysql, networking, nginx, replication

We have our database servers separate from our webserver.  The database servers are replicated (we know there is overhead here).  Even with replication turned off however, performance for large number of queries in a PHP script is 4 times slower than our staging server that has the db and apache on the same machine.  I realize that network latency and other issues with a network mean that there is no way they will be equal, but our productions servers are exponentially more powerful and our production network is all on gigabit switches.  We have tuned MYSQL as best as we can but the performance marker is still at 4x slower.  We are running over nginx with Apache proxies and replicated MYSQL dbs.  UCarp is also running.  What are some suggestions for areas to look for improving the performance?  I would be happy with twice as slow on production.

Comment: this is very hard for an external person to diagnose and make suggestions, it may be well worth hiring an expect contractor for a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to do much more than stab in the dark given your description, but here's some starting points to try independently, which will hopefully narrow down the cause:

- Move your staging DB to another host
- Add your staging host to the production pool and remove the others
- Profile your PHP script to ensure it's the queries causing the delay
- Use an individual MySQL server rather than via your load balancer
- Measure a single query to the production pool and the staging server from the MySQL client
- Run netperf between your web server and your DB cluster
- Profile the web server with [gb]prof
- Profile a MySQL server receiving the query with [gb]prof

If none of these illuminate anything other than the expected degradation due to the remote host, then please provide a reproducible test case and your full MySQL config (with sensitive data redacted.) That will help someone more skilled in MySQL assist you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not every web request on a web site will (if properly designed) need a mysql connection. Most likely, if you are requiring a connection on every http request, your application will not scale and will start having issues very quickly.

1. Do more caching at app. server to request mysql less often. E.g. use
   memcache.
2. Try to use persistent connections from application to your mysql servers.
3. Use mysql data compression.
4. Minify data (limit your selects, use column names instead of "*" in select statements)

Shamanic tuning:

- Make sure, that nothing slows down network at mysql servers: big firewall rulesets, network filters, etc.
- Add another (client inaccesible) network interface for app. server
  and mysql server.
- Tune network connection between app. server and mysql. Sometimes you
  can win several ms by creating hardcoded network routes.

Don't think any of above would help - if network connection is slow, nothing of above will significantly speed it up.